# Avoiding switch statements due to database types

Tags: c#, sql-server, design-patterns, nhibernate

I am currently working on a project with a database where i have several tables that contain only type enumerations. Things like:

```
OrderStatus:
ID | Description
1  | Open
2  | Shipped
3  | Canceled
...
```

When i get the types from the database and want to check them in code this usually results in a switch statement, which is somewhat hard to maintain especially when new items are added to the table.

```
switch(order.OrderStatus.ID) {
    case 1:
        handleOpenOrder();
        break;
    case 2:
        handleShippedOrder();
        break;
    case 3:
        handleCanceledOrder();
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Normally one would use inheritance to solve this but in this case i have to check for the type of value returned from the database at some point.

I currently get the orderstatus as a normal orderstatus entity from the database. Is there a way for an ORM (NHibernate) to automatically cast the entity to a more specific obejct? Like for instance an OrderStatusOpen class?

Comment: Is your main aim avoiding the switch statement or to automate the creation of a concrete order-handler?

Comment: The main goal is to avoid the switch statement, so that if a new oder status is added, i don't have to go through several classes fixing switch statements.

Comment: @narain Given that description your problem is not whether it's a `switch` statement or not, but rather that you have the exact same code scattered across several classes, rather than in one place.  Whether that one place uses a `switch` or some other mechanism wouldn't make a difference in either case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the order-handlers are all contained in one class and only used there, you could simply do something like the following and extend the `Dictionary<int, Action>` when a new handler-method is implemented:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly _handlerMap = new Dictionary<int, Action>
    {
        { 1, () => handleOpenOrder() },
        { 2, () => handleShippedOrder() },
        { 3, () => handleCanceledOrder() }
    }

    public void TheMethodPreviouslyContainingTheSwitch(Order order)
    {
        var action = _handlerMap[order.OrderStatus.ID];
        action.Invoke();
    }
}
```

If you have that switch-statement in several classes, I'd probably implement a class for each handler and extract a matching interface. I can elaborate on this if necessary.

**EDIT:**

The interface-based approach, I had in mind, would be basically the same. This may still not be the answer to everything ;-)
I wrote this from scratch (may not compile):

```
public interface IOrderHandler
{
    int StatusId { get; }
    void Handle(Order order);
}

public class OpenOrderHandler : IOrderHandler
{
    public int StatusId => 1;

    public void Handle(Order order)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public class OrderHandlerFactory
{
    // this factory could be injected to all you dependant classes that need
    // handlers to handle orders

    private readonly _handlerMap = new Dictionary<int, Action>
    {
        // defining the IDs here and in the classes' defintions may be a bit 
        // redudant, but... meh ;)
        { 1, () => new OpenOrderHandler() },
        { 2, () => new ShippedOrderHandler() },
        { 3, () => new CancledOrderHandler() }
    }

    public IOrderHandler CreateHandlerByStatus(int orderStatusId)
    {
        // if the creation of a handler is expensive, it may be useful to
        // only create a single handler that matches the orderStatusId
        var action = _handlerMap[orderStatusId];
        var handler = action.Invoke();
        return handler;
    }

    public ICollection<IOrderHandler> CreateHandlers()
    {
        // it may be fine to create all handlers in each call of this method
        // if the creation is inexpensive
        return _handlerMap.Select(kvp => kvp.Value.Invoke()).ToList();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    private readonly OrderHandlerFactory _orderHandlerFactory;

    public Foo(OrderHandlerFactory orderHandlerFactory)
    {
        _orderHandlerFactory = orderHandlerFactory;
    }

    public void TheMethodPreviouslyContainingTheSwitch(Order order)
    {
        var handler = _orderHandlerFactory.CreateHandlerByStatus(order.OrderStatus.ID);
        handler.Handle(order);
    }

    public void ThisMayBeUsefulIfMultipleHandlersRelateToAcertainStatus(Order order)
    {
        var handlers = _orderHandlerFactory.CreateHandlers();
        handlers
            .Where(handler => handler.StatusId == order.OrderStatus.ID)
            .All(handler => handler.Handle(order));
    }
}
```

Comment: Having a class for each handler would mean that i have some kind of type inference for the types wouldn't it? So i would a OpenStatus.class, ShippedStatus.class etc., but i can't see how that would work when i simply map the data from the database.

Comment: An ORM would be able to map the table contents to objects of _a certain_ type. But it would only do it in a data transfer object manner. So, from your three example entries above, you would get three objects that only hold the data in two properties: `ID` and `Description`

Comment: Exactly. So how would i use the approach using an interface you mentioned?